# JUnit 5 when using JUnit Platform Launcher API how to pass a custom object to running test method which is annotated with @TestFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot, automated-tests, junit5, junit-jupiter

I'm trying to run a series of tests dynamically. Imagine a scenario from main class I will be creating a launcher as below,

```
    Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
    
    LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request().
                            configurationParameter(META_TEST_INFORMATION_KEY, serializedString).
selectors(selectPackage("my.package")).build();
```

As you can see in the configurationParameter(META_TEST_INFORMATION_KEY, serializedString) section right now I have serialize a whole object and sent as it only supports String. But I need to pass a complex object like a FeignClient , JdbcClient etc (Which cannot be serialized) to the test class method below,

```
@ExtendWith(CustomParameterResolver.class)
public class JUnitTestRunner {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(JUnitTestRunner.class);

    @TestFactory
    Collection<DynamicTest> dynamicTestCollection(String data) throws TestFrameworkException {
        TestMetaData metaData = deserializeObject(data);
        List<DynamicTest> testList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < metaData.getGroupedOrderedTestCases().size(); i++) {

            TestCaseMetaInfo testCaseMetaInfo = metaData.getMapOfNumberedTestCaseMetaInfo().
                    get(metaData.getGroupedOrderedTestCases().get(i));
            testList.add(DynamicTest.dynamicTest(
                    testCaseMetaInfo.getName(),
                    () -> {
                        log.info("Running TEST Number " + testCaseMetaInfo.getCaseNumber());

                    }));
        }
        return testList;
    }

}
```

Below is my CustomParameterResolver,

```
public class CustomParameterResolver implements ParameterResolver {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(CustomParameterResolver.class);
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
        return parameterContext.getParameter().getType() == String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext)
            throws ParameterResolutionException {
        return extensionContext.getConfigurationParameter(META_TEST_INFORMATION_KEY).orElse("");
    }
}
```

Im not sure whether my approach is wrong but right now I only saw how to pass a string. Not a complex object. My ultimate goal is run series of tests using provided http client and a database client without creating them every time for each series of tests. Can you please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The JUnit API only allows String values as configuration parameters in the launcher. The reason is that discovering and launching tests potentially runs in a different JVM and process than test engine execution. All IDEs I'm aware of do that for instance.

Passing objects would therefore require some kind of (de-)serialization mechanism in order to transport them from one JVM to another. Sadly, Java has no reliable, generic and safe serialization mechanism.

What you could do:

- Serialize your complex object yourself into a String and use it as configuration parameter.
- Unserialize it in your parameter resolver implementation.

Comment: Thanks @johanneslink for the comment. Ya that is what I have done to pass a object with simple data. For other one time objects like http client object etc I used a static container to provide them for now.